# How to get Country name from Locale code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, country-codes

I want to get the country name from the Rails I18n.locale. I already tried https://github.com/hexorx/countries, but I only get the countries from country code.

Is there a better way rather than to hard code every locale with the country name? Thanks!

Comment: I don't really see how you imagine doing this as the results would be very ambiguous, take for example `:en` - should it return GB? US, India, Philipines or one of the other many places that use english as an official language? For a better example take Yiddish or Romani.

Comment: If you want to find the users location use a geospatial lookup via IP or the HTML5 geolocation API's.